# Javascript 'this' returns undefined inside object

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, this, arrow-functions

I have following code:

```
let myObj = {
  foo: "bar",
  getFoo: function() {
    console.log(this.foo);
  },
  method: function() {
    if (true) {
      window.addEventListener('scroll', this.getFoo);
    } else {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.getFoo);
    }
  }
}

window.addEventListener('click', () => {
  myObj.method();
});
```

It returns undefinded, since (for reasons unknown to me) `this` refers to the `window` object if `getFoo` is called as a callback in an `addEventListener` function.
Now if I used an arrow function inside `myObj.method` -

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  this.getFoo();
});
```

This would work, but then I called an anonymous function and can't do `removeEventListener` later.
How could I get this working with a non-anonymous function?

Comment: You have to write `myObj.getFoo` instead of `this.getFoo` The same goes for `this.foo`

Comment: `window.addEventListener('scroll', this.getFoo.bind(this))`.

Comment: Thank you for the reference, it was really useful to read about using object methods as callback functions. Also you are right, according to the reference you linked, the only way to do what I'd like using a non-anonymous function is `.bind`.

Comment: If you want to be able to use `removeEventListener` to remove the handler, you need to pass exactly the same value to it that you passed to `addEventListener`. I.e. if you use `.bind`, then you need to store the return value somewhere somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to call a method or function in the context of a certain object so that `this` refers to the context of `myObj`:

```
let myObj = {
  foo: "bar",
  getFoo: function() {
    console.log(this.foo);
  },
  method: function() {
    if (true) {
      // here you have to use bind to create a function in a certain context
      window.addEventListener('scroll', this.getFoo.bind(this));
    } else {
      // here is the same
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.getFoo.bind(this));
    }
  }
}

window.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // create and call method in the context of myObj or any other object that is passed as first parameter of call
  myObj.method.call(myObj);
  // or because this in the function method refers to myObj at the beginning, just call method with obj
  myObj.method();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but still returns undefined for me. Should this really work? Have you tried it?

Comment: You are welcome, sorry I only tested part of it. Now it should work.

Comment: Yeah, now it works, but the key was using `.bind`. With that, it works even without `.call(myObj)`, simply by calling `myObj.method()`

Comment: Assuming `if (true)` is actually containing a variable of some sorts, then removing the event handler won't work correctly. `.bind` always returns a new function, whereas you need to pass the exact same function object to `removeEventListener` that you passed to `addEventListener`.

Comment: `myObj.method.call(myObj);` is unnecessary btw. It's 100% the same as `myObj.method()`.

Answer (score 10):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function expression and does not have its own `this`, `arguments`, `super`, or `new.target`. These function expressions are best suited for non-method functions, and they cannot be used as constructors.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to take a quick look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), if you want to know how the "this" keyword actually works...

A solution for your problem might be to create a variable called `selfObj` (or something similar), then using that - to access the properties of `myObj`.

**Edit:** This version is tested and works. Not sure if it is simple enough anymore though... The key here is pass the exactly same parameters to both `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`. For that reason I have created the `scrollEventListener` array attribute for the `myObj` object. Then using [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) pass that as parameters...

Hope this helps...

```
'use strict';

    let myObj = {
        foo: 'bar',
        counter: 0,
        getFoo: function() {
            const selfObj = this;
            console.log(selfObj.foo);
        },
        scrollEventListener: [
            'scroll',
            function () {
                myObj.getFoo();
            },
            true
        ],
        method: function() {
            const selfObj = this;
            selfObj.counter++;
            if (selfObj.counter % 2 === 0) {
                window.addEventListener(...selfObj.scrollEventListener);
            } else {
                window.removeEventListener(...selfObj.scrollEventListener);
            }
        }
    };

    window.addEventListener('click', () => {
        myObj.method();
    });
```

Comment: Have you tested it? It's not working for me for some reason.

Comment: I am so sorry! Here's the problem:   `window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
      selfObj.getFoo();
     });`

Comment: So, basically you call the `selfObj.getFoo()` from inside an anonymous function, that you pass as a callback to the `addEventListener`. Hope that helps!

Comment: Let me know how that goes...

Comment: Still, `selfObj` is going to be the `window` object, when `getFoo` is called as a callback function. The only way I've managed to get it working is by  `bind`ing `this` to the callback for `addEventListener`.

Comment: Have you tried it? Copy and Paste the code that I've written above, change the last thing that I mentioned and then you should get "bar"... I've tried it and it works.

Comment: Yes, you're right, but then again - I won't be able to do `removeEventListener` on an anonymous function.

Comment: You should update your answer with the correct code. Because as it is it won't work. Also doing `const selfObj = this;` inside `getFoo` is unnecessary.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the remarks! I have updated my answer. Now it should both work for adding the event listener, as well as - for removing it. However, I am not sure in the simplicity of the answer anymore... Hope that helps now. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

If there is a `this` in anonymous function, `this` is points to window, not to object where you define it. than you use `function` , `this` is binds to object where you define this function.

Comment: *"this is binds to object where you define this function."* No, the value of `this` is determine by how a function is **called** not *when* or *how* it is defined (except for arrow functions). Whether a function us anonymous or not has not impact on `this`.